# Program account fails to change state of owned data account

Tags: solana-program, transactions, rust

I am working on a simple project, where a wallet account is created, credited some SOL, then assigned a program contract as its owner (via `assign` instruction). In the use case, the program should control the wallet's account funds.

The program code updates the balance of the owned account.

However, it is failing with a "instruction changed the balance of a read-only account" (which intrigues me, considering Solana Docs - [https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#:~:text=The%20security%20model%20enforces%20that,them%20via%20accounts%20they%20own.](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#:%7E:text=The%20security%20model%20enforces%20that,them%20via%20accounts%20they%20own.))

Transaction Instruction keys hold references to both accounts as 'isWritable: true', and transaction is signed with the program's key.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    let owned_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    let owner = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    msg!("Owned Account: {:?}", owned_account);
    msg!("Owner: {:?}", owner);

    if owned_account.owner != program_id {
        msg!("This account is not owned by the program");
        return Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId);
    }

    if owned_account.lamports() < 111111111 {
        msg!("Insufficient funds in the owned account");
        return Err(ProgramError::InsufficientFunds);
    }

    **owned_account.lamports.borrow_mut() -= 111111111;
    **owner.lamports.borrow_mut() += 111111111;

    msg!("Transferred 111111111 lamports from the owned account to the owner");

    // gracefully exit the program
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the cause of the error you're getting, but here are two examples from the Solana Developers repo you can reference for using PDAs and transferring SOL within a native Solana program.

https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/basics/transfer-sol/native

https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/basics/pda-rent-payer/native

Comment: I think I understand what I'm doing wrong. I have two accounts: owned data account A (holding origin funds), program account P, that owns the first.

My instruction attempts to transfer from account A to the destination (account P). Apparently there are 2 facts about account model I missed:

a) An account can only transfer SOL if it’s owned by SystemProgram. But account A is owned by program P; b) An executable account is read-only, therefore I cannot update P’s lamports directly (hence the error).

I need a 3rd vault account, V, whereas account A can only be used for P’s data storage?

Comment: It works now. `a) An account can only transfer SOL if it’s owned by SystemProgram` This is only true if done via the `Transfer` instruction. Updating the lamports state directly (as done in code above) works. Just had to do it via a third account, V. Thanks